# Twig C module not enabled causing issues with blocks?

Tags: blocks, 8, theming

I installed Drupal 8 on shared hosting and am having a problem in which blocks are not visible after I've placed them in a region. The blocks that came preinstalled with the themes are visible, but every new block that I place does not show up on the site. I did a status report and it said that Twig C extension is not available. I was wondering: could this could be something that affects the placement of blocks as Twig works with the new template system?

Comment: Drupal 8 doesn't require that Apache module to work. I am using Drupal 8 without it, and it works fine. It would work faster with it, but it surely shows any block I add without it.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question: No, the twig extension has absolutely nothing to do with that.

To actually figure out why your blocks don't show, you need to provide more information. Are you using a custom theme? How does the configuration of your blocks look like (screenshots of the block overview and edit page would be best).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I couldn't find anyone else that seemed to have the problem that I was having. However, I think I found out what was going wrong.

Drupal has a directory called **../sites** that I was having permission problems with. I found that the lack of permission was affecting other issues that I was having with my site with CSS and JavaScript files in **../sites/default/files**. I was granted permission to the files via my server administration. I uninstalled Drupal, reinstalled and all of my problems were resolved.

I use One.com for my hosting. It seems that the server has a script that created a directory called **Sites** whenever I completely emptied my home directory. The directory contained files for host parking that seemed to restrict certain permissions to me. The naming convention, I believe, may have been causing problems. After correcting the permissions and reinstalling Drupal, everything is perfectly fine.